# Ionic2 navigate like in slides

Tags: ionic2

Is there a way in Ionic 2 to be able to transition between pages as if we were in a [Slides component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/)? Meaning that as soon as I start swiping a little left or right I start seeing a piece of the next or previous page? If I continue swiping then I transition to the next/previous page, else I go back to seeing only my current page.

It's like having a dynamic slides component, where `ion-slide` are automatically added. A little bit like the way the infinite scroll works, we could have 2 to 3 `ion-slide` in the DOM and they'd be reused as we move forward/backward.

Comment: Looks like this feature will be introduced in beta 7 :) https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5101

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be available in beta 7 (we are in beta 6) for tabs in material design. The option to swipe back in the pages stack is already available but you must be running on a device to see it in action. Check out the Ionic2 road map to see whats up and coming: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qlc5X2eJyOB0izkFlH7KJ5BmMi0MeXUZRHJHt3hS6Wo/edit

Comment: Actually I'm not thinking of tabs, but more of a "slides component" with dynamic pages and size. Currently when I swipe forward I push a new page, and I swipe backward I pop a page. There is a transition but it's an all on nothing: if a swipe is detected, then the page will transition. It's not as if I swipe 10px and I see 10px of the next page, and then I can decide to continue swiping or not. I hope I'm making myself clear.